# Launch the Android dialer with a specific number

Tags: android, android-intent, phone-number, phone-call

The code I have works perfectly but all it does is launch the dialer. What I want it do is to be able to launch the dialer with a specific number. How can I do that?

```
bu5.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        //open the phone dialer on clicking the button
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
        startActivity(intent);   
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the tel: uri with the number into the intent, add this before the startActivity line.

```
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:1231231234"));
```